# Normaliser of image of induced representation

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory

I would like to compute the normaliser of the image of an induced representation. So it would be a representation from $GL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ to $GL_{n}(\bar{\mathbb{Z}}_{p})$. Is this maybe some well known result?

Comment: Well, the image of the induced representation embeds naturally in a wreath product ( in your case with base group a direct product of $\frac{n}{2}$ copies of the original group with a permutation group of degree $\frac{n}{2}$). The normalizer of the full wreath product is relatively easy to analyze, but I am not sure about the normalizer of  its subgroups. For example, if the original group is absolutely irreducible, then the centralizer of the full wreath product consists just of scalar matrices.